# Transform list of strings to list of case objects

Tags: scala

I have following case objects

```
sealed trait Type

case object Foo extends Type
case object Bar extends Type
```

I got a list of strings containing

```
Foo, Bar
```

Is there are way of transforming them to a list of case objects which are defined above?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a function that will convert your string to the given types

```
sealed trait Type

case object Foo extends Type
case object Bar extends Type

val inputList = List("Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar")

def convertToCaseObject(input: String) ={
  input match{
    case "Foo" => Foo
    case "Bar" => Bar
  }
}

val output = inputList.map(x => convertToCaseObject(x))
```

Here the function convertToCaseObject takes an input String, pattern matches them and gives the corresponding type as the output. So finally you end up getting the desired output.
Please reach out if you need any further information. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let us say,

```
sealed trait Type

case object Foo extends Type
case object Bar extends Type

  val inputList = List("Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar","Other","SomeJunk")

  inputList.map(x=>if(x=="Foo")Foo else if(x=="Bar") Bar else x )
```

### In Scala REPL:

```
scala> inputList.map(x=>if(x=="Foo")Foo else if(x=="Bar") Bar else x )
res33: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(Foo, Bar, Foo, Bar, Other, SomeJunk)
```

Comment: It seems like a better behavior would be to throw an exception on invalid strings.